# Why doesn't my discord bot help command work?

Tags: python, discord.py

My discord bot help command doesn't work. I want it to provide an embedded message with the commands available so I made the following:

```
@client.command(invoke_without_command = True)
async def help(ctx):
  em = discord.Embed(title = "Help", description = "Use &help <command> for get info about a specific command")

  em.add_field(name = "Moderation", value = "&kick, &ban, &unban, &mute, &unmute")

  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@help.command()
async def kick(ctx):
  em = discord.Embed(title = "Kick", description = "Kicks a member from the server", color = ctx.author.color)
  em.add_field(name = "**Syntax**", value = "&kick <@member>")
  await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

However, while running it, it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 125, in <module>
    @help.command()
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'command'
```

I have referred to many YouTube videos, however, all of them have used the same code and get no errors. Could you please help me fix the error?

Comment: Did you mean `@client.group` rather than `@client.command`?

Comment: Your suggestion worked, I will mark your answer as correct, but please post it as an answer and not a comment please.

Comment: Glad I could help. FlexGames can have the reputation, since they seem to have beaten me to it. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Silvio Mayolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2288659/silvio-mayolo) in the comments:

Solution was:    **Replace `@client.command` with `@client.group`**

Answer (score 0):

change `@help` to `@client` above your `async def kick`